# Entity framework many to many relations query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

I'm working on a project where I have two models that are related too each other. Books and BookCategories. I'm stuck on a function where I want to show all books that are in a certain category.
Like, display all books in the category "Horror". I know its in the alley somewhere with the .Include() function but I hit a dead end and would need some pointers to figure this out - Thank you!

This is how my models look like:

Models/book.cs

```cs
class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public List<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Models/BookCategory.cs

```cs
class BookCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

I know so far I can include the category with the books

```cs
db.Books.Include("BookCategory");
```

But I don't know how to match the criteria to tell I only want to get the books with a certain category

Comment: Why don't you start with  db.BookCategories.Include("Books").Where(bc => bc.Name == "Horror")  ?

Comment: Yes, but how would i then do a foreach to loop all the books with this category?

Comment: foreach(var book in horror.Books) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter by categories you can do something like this:

```cs
db.Books
  .Include("BookCategory")
  .Where(b => b.BookCategories.Any(c=>c.Name == "Horror"));
```

That should work, although I'm more accustomed to entity framework core now.